# Spring app basic auth over keycloack

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I need to add auth to my spring boot (MVC) app. Auth provider is keycloak via OpenID. Both Implicit and Authorization Code grants are disabled, so I am stuck with Resource owner credentials grant. What I want to achieve is basic auth prompt for unauthorized users. Credentials retrieved that way should be used to get token and user information from keycloak for its further usage by spring security. The token should be checked on each request.

Most examples I've found are using the redirect feature of `org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter`. Though I've found `enable-basic-auth` [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#java-adapters), It's not working for me. I am aware that I must use `keycloak.bearer-only=true` to turn off redirects, but it works so instead of redirecting it returns 401 for unauthorized users.

My security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

My keycloak properties (I don't use placeholders, it's just for the sake of security):

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://${keycloak.host}/auth/
keycloak.realm=master
keycloak.resource=${client.name}
keycloak.enable-basic-auth=true
keycloak.credentials.secret=${client.secret}
```

Sorry for the general question. I've mostly used jdbcAuthentication and it's my first experience with Identity Management software.

Comment: Note that in that doc you reference it says "If this option is enabled, then secret must also be provided. " That needs to be configured in your client adapter's config and also the realm too. See https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/basic-auth/basicauthrealm.json#L51 That's from the official keycloak basic auth example

Comment: @RyanDawson thanks for the response! Yeah, I have all this options turned on: `keycloak.credentials.secret=66666a66-66a6-6a66-666a-6a6a66aa666` and `Direct Access Grants Enabled` is on.

Comment: What is the failure behaviour that you see? I'm not clear on what you mean by 'not working'

Comment: @RyanDawson I've been able to achieve basic auth working with curl by removing `spring-boot-starter-security` and `SecurityConfig.java`, but in browser instead of getting Basic Auth prompt I get redirect. With `spring-boot-starter-security` and `SecurityConfig` basic auth doesn't work even with curl (`HTTP/1.1 302` `Location: http://localhost:8080/sso/login`). localhost:8080 is my application address.

Comment: Oh, yeah. After turning off `spring-boot-starter-security` I added some properties: `keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = content_managers`
`keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /admin/*`

Comment: Update: with SecurityConfig I get: `curl -v http://admin:Pa55w0rd@localhost:8080/admin/page` `< HTTP/1.1 401
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 15:20:06 GMT`

Comment: Update: custom authenticationEntryPoint needed and `keycloak.bearer-only=true`. There was a wrong header with `401` response. Should be `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Content"` I'll post code later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to add basic auth to your application over keycloak openid with Resource owner password credentials flow.

First of all you'll need to add this to pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

...

<dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

Add keycloak server properties:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://${keycloak.host}/auth/
keycloak.realm=master
keycloak.resource=${client.name}
keycloak.credentials.secret=${client.secret}
keycloak.enable-basic-auth=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

`enable-basic-auth` is actually responsible for enabling resource owner password credentials flow. So, every time you'll send request with Basic Authorization `BasicAuthRequestAuthenticator` will request token from keycloak. `bearer-only` is needed to turn off access code flow. Every time you'd make a request to secured resource without basic authorization (and outside authotized session) you'd get redirected to keycloak server - we don't want that. With `bearer-only` you'll get 401.

And last step is adding security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider provider = new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
                    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
                })
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Most interesting part here is this:

```
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        })
```

Standard keycloak `AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation is setting `WWW-Authenticate` header to `String.format("Bearer realm=\"%s\"", realm)` in case of authorization failure. I need it to be set to `Basic realm="Restricted Content"` for the basic auth prompt to pop up. If you want to avoid using this prompt (you want to add your own login form) - remove this part.

Comment: Hi, I am facing with same problem and do the same code. But it work only at first appeal and then when I input incorrect username and password, I get 401 with response header WWW-Authenticate = Bearer realm.
Have no idea how to fix this, cause I already use your gide, either wrote custom AuthAuthenticationEntryPoint

Comment: Hey Axel! Sorry, can't help your here, I don't remember this stuff already T_T

If you manage to make it work - feel free to post another answer to the question, I will accept it, I think it might help other people in the future.