# How to integrate Keycloak with Spring boot(API) without login page

Tags: rest, spring-boot, keycloak

There's need to integrate Keycloak with my spring boot application. What i need is that any REST request coming to my API will have a header e.g. "Authorisation" which will have value as "basic " to be used as auth token.
The request came to API should be validated from keyclaok without redirecting to any login page of keycloak.
All the tutorials to integrate keycloak with spring boot shows a login page or pre generated bearer token.

When i try to do this, below is my SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/myapi*").hasRole("user").anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

My application.properties:

```
server.port=8081
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:9080/auth
keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.resource=myclient
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.credentials.secret=mysecret
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.ssl-required=external
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example.api</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-kc-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springboot-kc-api</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Whenever a GET request is made, keycloak debug shows below log:

o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Sending redirect to login page: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fmyapi%2Fsampleget?param1=val1&state=a2b5072a-acb8-4bf6-8f33-b3f25deab492&login=true&scope=openid

Keycloak configuration:

```
Client Protocol : openid-connect
Access Type : confidential
Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:8081/myapi/*
```

Above setup working fine for an API written in Java REST Easy framework for one of existing application running on JBoss EAP 7.

Need help to understand how to configure spring boot API to use auth header in request to authenticate & authorise request.

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by enabling the `bearer only` mode. Start with enabling this in your spring boot service via `application.properties`:

```
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

See [1] for more details on this.

You can also enforce this inside the admin console for your client.

- [1] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config

Comment: if bearer-only is enabled, adapter will not attempt to authenticate users, but only verify bearer tokens. That's not I want. For me, it should also authenticate users.

Comment: @Saurabhcdt did You mange to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable basic auth in the adapter configuration and also send the client secret. What this will do is not redirect to login page but send 401 if the basic auth headers are missing.

```
keycloak.enable-basic-auth=true
keycloak.credentials.secret=${client.secret}
```

Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725873/spring-app-basic-auth-over-keycloack) for solution.

Comment: Adding keycloak.enable-basic-auth=true in application.properties now authenticating my request but if i dont pass any Authorization header in request, then also my API returns 200 OK response. This should have failed.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wanna give you the class which is created to talk to Keycloak through the api in spring boot. I think this will help you!

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder
import org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmResource
import org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.UsersResource
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class KeycloakComponent {

    @Value("\${keycloakconfig.server.url}")
    var serverUrl: String = ""

    @Value("\${keycloakconfig.username}")
    var username: String = ""

    @Value("\${keycloakconfig.password}")
    var password: String = ""

    @Value("\${keycloakconfig.realm}")
    var realmName: String = ""

    @Value("\${keycloakconfig.client.id}")
    var clientId: String = ""

    @Value("\${keycloakconfig.client.secret}")
    var clientSecret: String = ""

    val keycloak: Keycloak by lazy {
        KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .realm(realmName)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .resteasyClient(ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(20).register(CustomJacksonProvider()).build())
            .build()
    }

    val realm: RealmResource by lazy {
        keycloak.realm(realmName)
    }

    val userResource: UsersResource by lazy {
        realm.users()
    }


    fun keycloakForFetchUserToken(username:String, password: String): Keycloak {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .realm(realmName)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .resteasyClient(ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(20).register(CustomJacksonProvider()).build())
            .build()
    }

}
```

**If something does not make sense, do not hesitate to contact**

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? I don't see how the code solves the problem.